# Fastapi actual library for limits

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

I need to add limits for my fastapi endpoints. I'm currently using Fastapi-limiter. But there is a problem. The developer no longer supports the project. As well as slowapi (request pulls hang for almost a year). I'm currently using the patched version, of course. I would like to know if there are analogues known to you or something else to solve my problem. As an example, I attach just a piece of code (usual endpoint)

I want to thank you in advance for the time devoted to my problem, thank you.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Query, HTTPException, Depends, Request
    from fastapi_limiter import FastAPILimiter, default_identifier
    from fastapi_limiter.depends import RateLimiter
    
    router = APIRouter()
    
    limits_enabled = settings.limits_enabled
    
    async def custom_identifier(request: Request) -> None:
        return None
    
    
    if limits_enabled == 1:
        @router.on_event("startup")
        async def startup():
            redis = await aioredis.from_url(
                settings.redis_url,
                encoding="utf-8",
                decode_responses=True,
                password=settings.redis_pass
            )
            await FastAPILimiter.init(redis)
    
        @router.on_event("shutdown")
        async def shutdown():
            await FastAPILimiter.close()
    
        limits = [Depends(RateLimiter(times=settings.limiter_times,
                                      seconds=settings.limiter_seconds, identifier=custom_identifier))]

@router.get("/test", dependencies=limits, responses=example_vehicle_types_responses,
            response_model=schemas.test,
            description="test")
async def get_test():
    return "test"
```

Comment: You can usually apply rate limiting in the httpd that lives in front of your application as well, such as nginx - but this will depend on what your stack looks like. https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Comment: @MatsLindh 
Hello. At the moment the stack is: gunicorn (process manager), uvicorn, redis all in a docker container

Thanks for the advice. It helps a lot to look at it from a different angle.

Comment: I'd also be careful about dismissing slowapi (last commit two months ago) and fastapi-limiter (last commit five days ago); a lingering PR doesn't mean that a project isn't maintained, just that the PR might not be in a mergable state at the moment or that it needs further work to be merged.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I did not know this, I'll take a closer look at slowapi means.